# Draggable div won't save position into database using ajax and php

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, draggable

I have been trying to solve this problem for three days already. I'm trying to create a website where people can drag and drop the layout of a template in order to personalize their webpage, which means i'm using jquery and ajax in order for the elements in the webpage to be draggable. The code that i'm using is already good and experiencing no error whatsoever, my problem is that the position of the draggable div won't save in my database. thank you for the help and have a good day.

here is the code for my drag, drop and save .js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#col1" ).draggable({ 
stack: "#col1",
  stop: function(event, ui) {
      var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
      var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
      var username = ui.helper.data('username');

      //Do the ajax call to the server
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "coordsave.php",
          data: {x: pos_x, y: pos_y, username: username}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }); 
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

And here is my update to query function in PHP
     $x_coord=$_POST["x"];
     $y_coord=$_POST["y"];
     $username=$_POST['username'];

```
//Setup our Query
$sql = "UPDATE $coords SET x_pos='$x_coord', y_pos='$y_coord' WHERE user_uname =     '$username'";

//Execute our Query
if (mysql_query($sql)) {
      echo "success $x_coord $y_coord";
     }
    else {
    die("Error updating Coords :".mysql_error());   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you have connection to your db?
2. Chech the text of your query, maybe you have empty values

   $sql = "your query";
   echo $sql;

### Edit1:

see documentation here [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and use double quotes first of all and second of all do you have any value associated with key "username" in your DOM elements?

Comment: yes. the username part is empty. i want to get the username variable using $_GET['username'] from my url but it does not work. the x and y pos are returning values except for the username part

Comment: what do you pass to the function .data()? 'username' is a key or an object?

Comment: figured it out. i used location.search to get the username in the url and make it as an ID for verification. thanks for all the help!

Comment: if you found solution or answer on your question through my answer, accept it to resolve your question. [how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)